# How to specify what comes first when reading time values in pandas (hour, minute, seconds, day, month, year)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, timestamp

I have the following time data:

```
0        08/01/16 13:07:46,335437
1        18/02/16 08:40:40,565575
2        14/01/16 22:23:23,606399
3        18/01/16 12:12:46,114231
4        18/01/16 17:09:11,477728
5        20/01/16 12:56:20,432586
6        18/01/16 21:12:53,645333
7        25/01/16 17:29:34,540325
8        16/02/16 10:03:08,698522
9        16/02/16 13:49:54,977352
10       25/02/16 12:17:01,271601
```

This data is in european time format. (day, month, year). I want to tell pandas to read the dates in that order, the problem is that when i try `pd.to_datetime(format = "%d/%m/%Y")` it won't work, it says that my data is not in that format, i suppose that this is because i have also the hours minutes and seconds and i'm not telling pandas anything about how to read it. But i can't figure it out.

My question is simple, how can i read my data in this format??

My desired time format is days, month, year, hours, minutes, seconds.

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: I guess you should provide the full format if *reading* the data, it seems to be `"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S,%f"`...

Comment: Thank you @MrFuppes, but no, i tried it and it yells this error :
`ValueError: time data '08/01/16 13:07:46,335437' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S,%f' (match)`

Comment: sorry, must be lower case y, `%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S,%f`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use parameter `format` in [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), parameters is possible find in [`http://strftime.org/`](http://strftime.org/):

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S,%f')
```

Explanation:

```
%d - match day  
%m - match month  
%y - match year in format YY  
%H - match hour in 24h format  
%M - match minute  
%S - match second  
%F - match microsecond
```

Comment: Great Jezrael!! That worked just fine, thank you very much. Can you provide some explanation about how the dates are processed with the time format you used please?

Comment: @Miguel2488 - not sure if understand - Can you explain more?

Comment: I would like to know what your time fomat `'%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S,%f'` is doing a bit more in depth please

Comment: Great buddy, as always, your answers are truely helpful :) Thank you very much again